# Creating an output based off of input

Tags: java, input, output

I am trying to create a Java program where a patient inputs their symptoms such as "headache" into the console, and the output is based off of that input.

For example, if a patient inputs "Chest pain", the output will be based on the input. In this case, the system will print "Your recommended doctor is Sally from the cardiology department." I am not very good at programming so any help will be great!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this in Java, you will need to somehow accept user input, process it and give a logical response.

## Input

You might choose to use one of the following
- console application
- desktop application
- web application
- mobile application

You will need to handle user input in accordance with the application type you have chosen. Of course, users must be guided by the application so they will not waste their time trying to find out how can they complain about chest pain, for example. If you create a console application, then at startup describe somehow the way they need to work. If it's graphical, then design it in such a way that it will be easy-to-use. Documentation would not hurt either.

## Mapping

You will need to somehow map possible choices with doctors. You can hard-code this into your application, but don't forget that doctors and departments change over time. You will need a database and an admin UI where doctor data can be maintained. It would not hurt to store the possible complaints in the database and load them before you show them to your users.

## Logic

You will need to somehow map doctors with complaints. Plan your database accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a VERY SIMPLE program you can very well use a dictionary as well as a **hashmap** where you put the symptom as the key and the "advice" as the value.

Look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Creation of the dictionary
        Map<String, String> illnessesDict = new HashMap<>();
        illnessesDict.put("Chest pain", "Your recommended doctor is Sally from the cardiology department.");
        // Put other entries...

        // Ask for the symptom
        String symptom = sc.nextLine();
        // Search in the dictionary if there's an advice for that symptom
        String advice = illnessesDict.get(symptom);
        if(advice == null)
            System.out.println("There is no entry for this symptom");
        else
            System.out.println(advice);
}
```